# Do overpopulated rats have extremely high infant mortality rates caused by competition and stress?

Tags: biology, ethology

[Dr John B. Calhoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_B._Calhoun) conducted [a series of experiments](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1501789/pdf/califmed00143-0080.pdf) in the 1960's on the effect of over-population on [Norway rats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_rat).

Wikipedia [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_B._Calhoun):

> The conclusions drawn from this experiment were that when all available space is taken and all social roles filled, competition and the stresses experienced by the individuals will result in a total breakdown in complex social behaviors, ultimately resulting in the demise of the population.

His own paper describes infant mortalities of 80% or 96% depending on the experiment.

Have these results been replicated? Are they considered solid science by today’s experts?

Comment: Its seems pretty likely to be true, I would be more surprised if the opposite case was made.